# Solaris disk failed, how to remove it?

Tags: solaris, hard-disk

I have a system with Solaris 10. One of the internal disks is broken:

```
c0t0d0s2     auto:sliced    rootdisk1_1  rootdg      online               c0t0d0s2         -
c0t1d0s2     auto           -            -           error                c0t1d0s2         -
c1t0d0s2     auto:sliced    rootmirror1_1  rootdg      online               c1t0d0s2
c1t1d0s2     auto:sliced    rootmirror2_1  rootdg      online               c1t1d0s2         -
```

When I run the `format` command, it becomes hung, because of the c0t1d0s2 disk. Is there a way to completly remove it from the system so that `format` can work again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from my emergency response notes. I neglected to mention the Solaris version and no longer have a recent Solaris box to check this on, so check the manpages and give it a try if it seems appropriate.

First things first, you **must** `umount` any volumes on that disk, disable swap on it, and in every other say stop using it (e.g. if you're using Solaris software RAID). If you're using Veritas, check out rkosegi's answer.

Then, find out what `cfgadm` calls the disk:

```
cfgadm -al
```

The left column is the disk designation. Yes, I know, yet *another* format. At least this one includes the short block device name so it's not too difficult to find. Anyway, once you know it, say something like this: (based on your question, but *do* check first):

```
cfgadm -c unconfigure c0::dsk/c0t1d0
```

You can say `cfgadm -al` again to make sure the disk has been unconfigured. At this point, if your machine has hot-swappable disks, the disk will have been tri-stated, powered off, and controllers, backplanes etc. will be aware that you're about to remove it. If the disk has a ‘ready to remove’ light, it'll illuminate.

Once you're done replacing it:

```
cfgadm -c configure c0::dsk/c0t1d0
```

Once the disk is configured again, you can proceed with the rebuild. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And what if the disk is in a Veritas disk group in the rootdg? Should I boot in single user and then remove it with the cfgadm magic?

Comment: I've always avoided Veritas like the plague, so I don't know. But rkosegi has just posted an answer that might help you. I edited the answer to include this.

Answer (score 4):

If disk is under VX then you must unconfigure it from Veritas:

If you want to replace it with new one, follow this [article](http://sfdoccentral.symantec.com/sf/5.0MP3/solaris/html/vxvm_admin/ch02s18.htm)

To remove VX metadata run following command:

```
# /usr/lib/vxvm/bin/vxdiskunsetup c0t1d0
```

Comment: Sadly the vxdiskunsetup still remains in hang. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it still reamins in hang, too.